# ViewPager2 not updating fragment with POSITION_NONE

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-viewpager2

I have implemented ViewPager2 and implemented with 2 tabs. I want to refresh each fragment between consecutive swipe with the following code but it is not working.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

It throws following crash error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp, PID: 5842
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$Tab com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$Tab.setIcon(int)' on a null object reference
```

Please suggest appropriate way to accomplish this.

Comment: Can you try by checking when the fragment becomes visible(`setUserVisibleHint`) and then refresh the fragment , also do you want to refresh each fragment when we swipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, this issue by updating UI from onResume method of fragment life cycle.